# Visual studio: how to make C++ consoleApplication use more of CPU power?

Tags: c++

so i am running a console project, but when the code is running i see in Task manager that only 5% (2.8 GHz) of Cpu is been used, of course i am not exacly sure how cpu distribute the proccessing power in windows to begain with. but for more of a future reffrence i would like to know if i had a performance demanding code that i need the answer faster how would i do that?
here is the code if you would like to know:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
    int i;
    if (l == r)
        cout << a << endl;
    else
    {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
            permute(a, l + 1, r);
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char Short[] = "ABCD";
    int n1 = strlen(Short);
    char Long[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int n2 = strlen(Long);
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Would you like to see the permutions of only a) ABCD or b) the whole alphabet?!\n(please enter a or b): ";
        char input;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 'a') 
        {
            cout << "The permutions of ABCD:\n";
            permute(Short, 0, n1 - 1);
            cout << "-----------------------------------";
        }
        else if (input == 'b') 
        {
            cout << "The permutions of Alphabet:\n";
            permute(Long, 0, n2 - 1);
            cout << "-----------------------------------";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "ERROR! : Enter either a or b.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

i found the code in a blog to show the permutions of "ABCD" as part of an assgiment but i also used it for the entire alphabet, and i wanted to know for that use is there a way to make code use more cpu?(it's kinda taking a much longer time than i expected)

Comment: Sounds like you want to employ [parallel computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) techniques.

Comment: Consult both the Windows API and folklore about how Windows schedules things (e.g., at one time an application that called `Yield` often would get more CPU). I can only recount from my student days, how I discovered that a process under MPE IV on the HP3000 mini-computer, got more CPU if/when it did user input. So I made my computation of pi input a line of text every tenth of a second or so, and inserted a matchstick on the side of the keyboard's return key. It worked! Except that nobody else got anything done, so the computer guy came to have a little chat with me.

Comment: you're only using 1 of the (probably 4) cores of your cpu with this code. So theoretically you could only possibly get to 25% cpu usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Learning to optimize code efficiently is a major challenge for the even experienced coders, and there are volumes of books, articles, and presentations on the topic. As such, a complete treatment is well out of scope for a Stack Overflow question.

That said, here are a few principles:

- **Focus initially on the algorithm**. You can write a messy bubble sort or an efficient one, but in most 'real world' cases quicksort will beat either handily. This is arguably the primary reason the field of *computer science* exists: the study and selection of algorithms and their theoretical performance.

> Related to this, make sure you are comparing your implementation against a 'stock' algorithm when possible. For example, you should see how your implementation performs compared to using the C++11 `std::random_shuffle` in the `<random>` header.

- **Optimize the compiler settings first**. Debug builds are never going to be fast, and they aren't supposed to be. Using `inline` can help, but only happens if the compiler is actually doing inline optimizations. For Visual C++, there are a number of different optimization settings you can try out, but remember that there are tradeoffs so `/Ox` (maximum optimization) may not always be the right choice, which is why most templates default to `/O2` (maximize speed). In some cases, `/O1` (minimize space) is actually better.
- **Always measure performance before and after optimization.** Modern out-of-order CPUs are sophisticated systems, and they don't always do what you think they are doing. In many cases, what is a textbook optimization in code actually performs worse than the original code due to various pipelining and microarchitecture effects.  The only way to know for sure is to use a good profiler, have solid test cases, and measure the impact of any optimization work. If it's slower on average than before, then revert to the 'unoptimized' version and try something else.
- **Focus optimization on the hotspots**. This is the so-called '80/20' rule. In many applications the vast majority of the code is run rarely, so only a few areas of your application are actually spending enough time running to be worth optimizing.

> As a corollary to this rule, having all of your code using extremely inefficient anti-patterns can really hurt the baseline performance of your entire application. For this reason, it's worth knowing how to write *good* code generally. The point of the 80/20 rule is to spend your limited time optimizing on the areas that will have the most impact rather than what you as the programmer assume matters.

All that said, in your case none of this matters. The vast majority of the CPU time is spent just creating your process and handling the serialized input and output. When dealing with an `n` of 4 or 26, it doesn't matter how bad or good your algorithm is. In other words, it is highly unlikely `permute` is your program's 'hotspot' unless you are working with tens of thousands of millions of characters.

Answer (score 3):

> NOTE: Yes I am oversimplifying the topic, but I'm concerned that
>   without this basic understanding, the more advanced topics will
>   actually lead to some disastrous program designs.

Maybe I'm missing something, but there also seems to be a misunderstanding regarding the link between CPU and efficiency in your mind.

Your program has N instructions, and the CPU will process those N instructions at relatively the same speed (3.56 GHz is about 3.56 billion instructions per second). That's the same (more or less), whether you're getting "5%" or "25%" use of the CPU from a single program. (I'll explain that percentage in a moment.)

The only way to get "faster" in terms of processor usage, as erip said, with parallel computing techniques, which in a nutshell employ multiple CPUs to accomplish the task.

If you think of it like an assembly line, your one worker can only process one widget at a time. If your batch of widgets to him takes up 5% of his time, that means that in order to process ALL of your widgets one-by-one, he uses 5% of his time, and the other 95% is not needed for that batch (and he'll probably use it for some other batches other people assigned him.)

He cannot process more than one widget at a time, so that's as fast as he'll get with your batch. You might be able to make things appear faster by having him alternate between two different types of widgets, instead of finishing all of batch A before starting on batch B, but it will still take the same amount of time in the end to process both batches.

> MASSIVE EXCEPTION: If he's spending 100% of his time on someone else's batch of widgets, you're literally going to have to cool your heels. That's not something you can do a thing about.

However, if you add another worker to that assembly line, they can process twice (roughly) the widgets in the same amount of time, because you are processing two widgets at once. When we say you have a "quad core processor", that basically means that you have four workers available (literally 4 CPUs). Each one can only process a single instruction at once, but by assigning more than one to the batch of widgets, you get it done faster.

---

All of this said, one must keep in mind that those CPUs are doing a lot - they run the entire computer. You want to try and keep those percentages *down* as much as possible, so your program is fast and responsive on any supported computer. Not all of your users will have 3.46 GHz quad-core machines, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the reason this program is not using all available CPU bandwidth is because it's emitting the permutation results to the screen once for each permutation. This will result in blocking I/O within the implementation of `cout`.

If you want 100% cpu use you'll want to separate computation from I/O. In this case you'd then need to either:

a) store the results for later output, or

b) communicate results across a thread boundary (which will itself have a an efficiency cost because of the cost of acquiring mutexes and synchronising cache memory), or

c) a combination of the above (batching results and communicating them across the thread boundary)

For a quick check, you could remove comment out all the `cout` calls and see how much CPU use you get (as mentioned it will be close to 100% divided by the number of CPUs on your computer).